# How do I stop controller execution after using redirect_to? (Using Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I have a controller with multiple actions that take :year and :month as
attributes from the URL. I have made a private method check_date to
check the date is valid and check the date is not in the future.

```
def check_date(year, month)
  if month < 1 || month > 12 || year < 2000
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'archive.invalid_date'
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  elsif year > Date.today.year || (year == Date.today.year && month > Date.today.month)
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'archive.no_future'
    redirect_to :action => 'month_index', 
      :year => Date.today.year, 
      :month => Date.today.month,
      :type => params[:type]
  end
end
```

Is there a rails way of ending controller execution after the
redirect_to?

Ways I can think of are either to throw an exception after the redirect_to or to return a value from check_date and check it in each action that calls it - something like

```
def month_index 
  year = params[:year].to_i
  month = params[:month].to_i
  if !check_date(year, month)
    return
  ...
end
```

But I wonder if there is some nice rails way of doing this. I was half
hoping that having called redirect_to rails would recognise I wanted to
stop, but that doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You probably want to use filters.

If you call your `check_date` as a `before_filter` in the controller, the fact that it rendered or redirected will prevent the controller from ever calling the action method. It ends there and then.

Comment: This may solve the asker's problem but I came here expecting a solution like vrish88's.

Answer (score 53):

You can also do:

```
return redirect_to :action => 'index'
```

and

```
return redirect_to :action => 'month_index', 
  :year => Date.today.year, 
  :month => Date.today.month,
  :type => params[:type]
```

since it looks nicer than putting return on its own line (IMHO).

Comment: Or `redirect_to :action => 'index' and return`

Comment: I do but "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action"

Comment: @Matrix Unfortunate.  It looks like this no longer works in Rails 5.

Comment: @Rigo I don't think it is safe your idea, because if `redirect_to` returns a falsy value then your `return` will be ignored!

Answer (score 16):

You can throw in

```
return false
```

wherever you want the code execution in your action to stop

Comment: actually, just a return will do.

Comment: yes but when it is in a private function I have to check return values so I was looking for a more automatic way - like the before_filter

Comment: @HamishDowner In that case, I would definitely have the private function return the state in a form native to what it's doing, i.e. a symbol if it returns other symbols, a `false` if it would normally return `true`, a `nil` if it normally returns other data, or maybe even a form of an out variable or an exception if that seems best for the helper. Then the controller should pick up on however the private function expresses the negative state, and react to that. Mixing the controller method's functionality into a private function not only gets messy fast, it hinders reusability.

Answer (score 7):

redirect_to just tells rails what to render when it finishes.  Rails will get confused if you add other render or redirect_to directives after the one you really want, so just return from the controller after the redirect_to - it's the 'normal' rails way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP is confused about the function of `redirect_to`.

`redirect_to` will redirect at the end of the action. However, the rest of the controller function will execute as usual. All you have to do (as posted by other people) is to include a return, as you should any other function call.