# adding multiple levels of user access

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im trying to add multiple levels of users in my application and this is the idea i could come up with :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 before_filter :setup , :authorize
protect_from_forgery

 def setup
 @minimum_permission = "admin"
end  

def authorize
  perm = { admin: 3 , moderator: 2 ,  reader: 1 }
  perm.default = 0
  if    User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
        unless perm[session[:user_permission].to_s.to_sym] >= perm[@minimum_permission.to_sym]
            redirect_to global_login_url, notice: "you need to have "+@minimum_permission+" privileges to access this page"
        end
  else
        redirect_to global_login_url, notice: "Please log in"
  end
end
end
```

and in my view ill do something like :

```
class FieldsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :authorize
# GET /fields
# GET /fields.json
def index
@minimum_permission = "moderator"
authorize
  @fields = Field.all   
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @fields }
  end
  end
....
end
```

and this is my sessions controller:

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_filter :authorize
  def new
  end

 def create

user = User.find_by_cpf_no(params[:cpf_no])
if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  session[:user_permission] = user.permission
  session[:user_name] = user.name
  redirect_to fields_url, alert: "successfully logged in"
else
  redirect_to fields_path, alert: "Invalid user/password combination"
end
 end

 def destroy
session[:user_id] = nil
session[:user_permission] = nil
session[:user_name] = nil
redirect_to root_path, notice: "Logged out"
 end
end
```

this works fine for a person who is logged in! but when i try to visit the index without already being logged in, i get this error:

"Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"."

how can i fix this? and also is there any better way of handling multiple levels of users?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So somewhere you have a before filter or other redirect sending you round in circles. The log should have given you atleast one of the lines that tried to redirect. I'd start by checking that global_login_url (not path?) is skipping all filters and that it the func exits after rendering and doesn't hit another on further down.

Comment: u were right about the error. turns out my index controller didn't stop executing even after my redirect_to(). using a "return redirect_to()" according to the answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820781/how-do-i-stop-controller-execution-after-using-redirect-to-using-rails

by slipp douglas solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

There’s great libraries out there which should do what you need pretty much out of the box. Have a look at [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) e.g.. In cancan's wiki you can find an entry on [role based authorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) as well.